# How to implement CAPTCHA in a form using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery.

I have got the JQuery Dialog Login form, now I want to implement the captcha on the form if users inputs is invalid.

I am using JQuery to check all the form validation and finally my main form is submitted.

Please suggest the some good example or the page links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Captcha in pure javascript/jQuery doesn't exist since JS is disabled for *robot*. It'd be useless.

Anyway, you can implement it with PHP or any dynamic language.

[A quick search](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+captcha) would have give you a lot of results

For example :

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/simpleCaptcha

http://www.webdesignbeach.com/beachbar/ajax-fancy-captcha-jquery-plugin (w/o jQuery)